# Вопрос о путях

Tags: php

Привет.
Подскажите мне пожалуйста.

```
`var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) ))`
```

здесь получаю абсолютный путь к родительской папке(public).

`var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'))`-почему я таким образом получаю папку /application, которая размещена в той же директории что и папка public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему вы должны получить что-то другое?

dirname(**FILE**) - ваша папка "public"

../ - выходим на уровень вверх

application - получаем папку.

Какой результат вы ожидали?

Comment: Я не знал что ../ можно писать всередине пути.Пока не встречал.Благодарен